# Пропал перевод в списке отозванных и в устаревших тревог

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, история-тревог

- Вот дефект номер один (нет перевода двух слов на [странице со списком отозванных тревог](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/current?group=1&status=6)):

[image: Проблема номер один]

- А вот дефект номер два (нет перевода двух слов на [странице со списком устаревших тревог](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/current?group=1&status=5)):

[image: Проблема номер два]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавил переводы:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19050
- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/19053

Будет в новых сборках. Текущая  2023.3.22.43342